# Windows Terminal vs Ubuntu.exe

Tags: windows-terminal

What's the difference between using an Ubuntu tab on Windows Terminal vs using the Ubuntu app for Windows (ubuntu.exe)?

I've only noticed that each start at a different directory:

WT: :/mnt/c/Users/username

Ubuntu: /home/username

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences between using an Ubuntu tab on **Windows Terminal** vs using `ubuntu.exe` on it's own:

Both are terminal applications that use 'Console Windows Host' (conhost.exe) however **Windows Terminal** is superior in [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/), is open source, has many improvements over 'ubuntu.exe' (and `wsl.exe`) and **Windows Terminal** utilizes two additional programs when it is run, `OpenConsole.exe` and `windowsTerminal.exe`.

These two programs `OpenConsole.exe` and `windowsTerminal.exe` are what makes all the new features in **Window Terminal** possible such as configurable starting locations, custom color schemes, full color support and much much more. There is a little history as to the origins of Windows Terminal and what I am talking about [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal#terminal--console-overview).

`ubuntu.exe` and `wsl.exe` on their own (with plain old conhost.exe) are really just here for backwards compatibility at this point.